# how to limit items shown when using MiniProfiler For MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using MiniProfiler for my MVC6 project. MiniProfiler Shows 10 items, I would like to change the default behavior so that it only shows 5 items in maximum. is there any settings for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit this for the entire app by setting `MiniProfiler.Settings.PopupMaxTracesToShow = 5` in your app startup (defaults to 15) or in the code-behind for a specific page by setting `MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes(maxTracesToShow: 5);`.